# How to use Mapping Data flow to flatten hierarchy of a JSON string column in Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have CSV files in a container in Data Lake and I am trying to transform the attribute column(which is in json) in the files into multiple columnns. When I try using Data flows to do that, It recognizes the attribute column as string and I am unable to change it to array so that I can either flatten or create derived columns out of it. Am i doing something wrong here
CSV File Format:

| ID | Name | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Test | {"Referrer URL":null,"Query Parameters":"topics"} |
| 456 | Test2 | {"Referrer URL":"www.google.com","Query Parameters":"WebTopics"} |

After following guidance of Mark and Joseph:
Issues faced while using parsing function and removing spaces from keys in json objects in those columns

1. wouldn't the replace function also remove spaces from the values associated with those keys. That could be an issue if we get sentence type data in those fields.
2. I am still running into issues when I follow all the steps mentioned by Joseph.  It may be associated with how I set up the dataset. If I use data preview to inspect the data, I see the the source does not properly fill up the columns. In the example, it just stops after Refferer URL being null and does not show the other values as well as the closing brackets of the json object in the column. adding pictures of datalake connection setup.

[image: after following all steps]

[image: Connection settings]
[image]
[image: Actual values in Excel]

Comment: Hi@Hammad Hassan Kandly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi @josephXu thanks for your help. I am still running into issues that I have added in my original question.

Comment: Hi@Hammad Hassan Khan, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
Hi@Hammad Hassan Khan, due to your `Attribute` column contains "," character, so I edit it as follows. And use Pipe (|) as Column delimiter in the source:
[image]

---

Attached to the answer given by @Mark Kromer MSFT. Yes we can use [Parse transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse) in mapping data flow to achieve that. But the `Parse` activity does not support JSON objects whose keys contain space characters. Therefore, we need to replace space characters.

I created a simple test for this. And the result is as follows:
[image]

1. The data source is as follows:
   [image]
2. In `DerivedColumn1` activity. Select `Attribute` column, enter expression `replace(Attribute,' ','' )` to replace spaces in keys. Because in the next `Parse1` activity, it does not support keys contain space characters.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
3. In `Parse1` activity, select `Attribute` column, enter `Attribute` as **Expression**, enter `(ReferrerURL as string,QueryParameters as string)` as **Output column type**.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Hi Mark and Joseph, Thanks for the answers. I believe that I was previously facing issues with spacing in the keys. I am running into 2 issues now. One is using 'replace' function. Wouldn't it also remove spaces in the values for those keys?.
The other issue that I am facing is that even after following all the steps, I am getting null values populated in the columns. I am guessing that this may have something to do with how I configured the dataset. Under data preview, I only see half the values and not the proper value of that column if I open it as a CSV.

Comment: Spaces in column names are supported for JSON. Post the dataflow script(not code) and a sample data file.

Comment: Hi@Kiran-MSFT. When I wrote the expression in the 3rd step, if there is a space in the key, it will report an error. I tried several ways, eg. add `{ }` to the keys, but with no luck. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYxvw.png)

Comment: Hi@Hammad Hassan Khan. Using 'replace' function will also remove spaces in the values.

Comment: Hi@Hammad Hassan Khan we can replace('Referrer URL','ReferrerURL')  and replace('Query Parameters','QueryParameters').

Comment: Thanks for the guidance here @JosephXu. I did need to add additional steps to make the complex columns as string data type, as complex columns can't be pushed as a CSV file, to data lake, and parse function creates the new columns as complex data type. So just had to put the extra step. But the rest were the steps that you had provided and it worked. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Because your JSON string is actually a string field inside of a delimited text file, you first need to parse it using the Parse transformation. Now that "Attribute" is a JSON data type, you can then work with the structures and arrays inside of it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse

Choose "Attribute" as your Expression property and give a name for the Column property. ADF will create a new hierarchical column based on that new name with the properties being the columns that you identify in the output property.