# ADF: Converting output to JSON format

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have two input feeds. First feed holds customer details (Customer number, name, addrs1, postcode) ans second feed holds product details of the customer (Customer number, product number, product tariff).

I need to join both the feeds. As customer can have multiple tariff, the output can produce multiple records for same customer with different products.

Like

```
Customer1 product1 
customer product2
```

I want to convert this into JSON format using ADF. My output will be like

```
CustomerDetails
{
    Name:XXX
    Address: XXX
}

ProductDetails
{
Product1:
Product2:
}
```

How can I convert join output to above JSON format?

Comment: Can you use data flow in ADF?

Comment: I have managed it using aggregate and collect functions. Only challenge i have now is, output JSON is coming as one string. I need to add new line character after each row. Any help how can I achieve this please. Kumar

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
OP finally used aggregate and collect fuction to convert from text to JSON.

---

As what Mark said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67407817/13979487), we need to parse it using the [Parse transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse). Choose "Attribute" as your Expression property and give a name for the Column property. ADF will create a new hierarchical column based on that new name with the properties being the columns that you identify in the output property. By the way, you'd better provide a json string you have with fake data. So I can help you do the experiment together. :)

Comment: Thanks. I need to convert from text to JSON rather turning JSON into text. I have achieved it using aggregate and collect fuction. It's all working fine. Thanks for your help.